# scale(0.01) shows parent's background color between children - how to prevent this?

Tags: css

When a very large element scaled down, it shows it's background between children elements.
How can I prevent that from happening?

[image]

The expected result is a solid green square

```js
/* adding 100 children */
for(let i = 0, div = document.querySelector(".parent"), child = document.createElement("div"); i < 100; i++)
  div.appendChild(child.cloneNode());
```

```css
.parent
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0.01);
}

.parent > *
{
  width: 2048px;
  height: 2048px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is fit a div into window, which contains a series of images, arranged into a grid, which together make a large image. And allow user zoom in/out. At first I was changing size of children, which worked fine, but with poor performance, now I'm trying use `scale()` on parent and see if it would work better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Chrome already opened long time ago, seems is not fixed yet:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=600120

Why dont you set a background of the parent element to green as well?

Comment: because it's just an example, the image I'm working on is not a solid color, so setting background to anything will not do any good.